# passing variable to OLE DB Source in oracle data source SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have the following query , I want to load only the data where `last_update_date` is greater than one of the value, I delure the value in correct way and its working in SQL Server data source but when I use Oracle date source its not working. Also I try to change the quotation mark with :VARIABLENAME it gives me this error:
not all variables bound

```
SELECT 
PAPF.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER NatnlIdNum,
PAY.PAYROLL_NAME PayrollName,
DEP.NAME DepartmentName,
PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.USER_STATUS EmploymentStatDesc,
EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.MEANING EmploymentCatDesc,
PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS.SEGMENT4 PositionName,
PAAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE EffectiveStartDate,
PAAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE EffectiveEndDate,
PG.NAME GradeName,
FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF
INNER JOIN  PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F PAAF
ON PAPF.PERSON_ID=PAAF.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN PAY_ALL_PAYROLLS_F PAY
ON PAAF.PAYROLL_ID=PAY.PAYROLL_ID
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAY.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
AND PAY.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
LEFT JOIN PAY_PEOPLE_GROUPS PPG
ON PAAF.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID=PPG.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS DEP
ON PPG.SEGMENT2=DEP.ORGANIZATION_ID
LEFT JOIN fnd_lookup_values EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY
ON  PAAF.EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY=EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.lookup_code
AND EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.language='AR'
AND EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.lookup_type='EMP_CAT'
LEFT JOIN PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL
ON PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID=PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID
AND PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.language='AR'
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F 
ON PAAF.POSITION_ID=HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.POSITION_ID
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
AND HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
LEFT JOIN PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS 
ON HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.POSITION_DEFINITION_ID=PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS.POSITION_DEFINITION_ID
LEFT JOIN PER_GRADES PG
ON PAAF.GRADE_ID=PG.GRADE_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS SCHOOL
ON PPG.SEGMENT5=SCHOOL.ORGANIZATION_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS ED
ON PPG.SEGMENT6=ED.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PAAF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >?
```

Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provider might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which the entire SQL command is stored in a variable. ORA-00920: invalid relational operator (OraOLEDB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the query in a string variable, then use the "SQL command from variable" option in the OLE DB Source and add the parameter in the query.  However when doing this, **make sure that the date format passed into the Oracle data source is the date format that is expected.**  To concatenate the date parameter within the string variable holding the SQL, it will need to be cast to a string, the format will still be preserved, however this doesn't guarantee that it will be passed as a date data type and casting may be necessary.  Also, note that the string casting function `(DT_STR, number of characters, code page)` will return an error if the length of the string that's converted is longer than the specified length and it's subsequently truncated.  An example expression for the SQL in a string variable follows.

```
"SELECT 
PAPF.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER NatnlIdNum,
PAY.PAYROLL_NAME PayrollName,
DEP.NAME DepartmentName,
PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.USER_STATUS EmploymentStatDesc,
EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.MEANING EmploymentCatDesc,
PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS.SEGMENT4 PositionName,
PAAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE EffectiveStartDate,
PAAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE EffectiveEndDate,
PG.NAME GradeName,
FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF
INNER JOIN  PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F PAAF
ON PAPF.PERSON_ID=PAAF.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN PAY_ALL_PAYROLLS_F PAY
ON PAAF.PAYROLL_ID=PAY.PAYROLL_ID
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAY.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
AND PAY.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
LEFT JOIN PAY_PEOPLE_GROUPS PPG
ON PAAF.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID=PPG.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS DEP
ON PPG.SEGMENT2=DEP.ORGANIZATION_ID
LEFT JOIN fnd_lookup_values EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY
ON  PAAF.EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY=EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.lookup_code
AND EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.language='AR'
AND EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY.lookup_type='EMP_CAT'
LEFT JOIN PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL
ON PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID=PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID
AND PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_TL.language='AR'
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F 
ON PAAF.POSITION_ID=HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.POSITION_ID
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
AND HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
LEFT JOIN PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS 
ON HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F.POSITION_DEFINITION_ID=PER_POSITION_DEFINITIONS.POSITION_DEFINITION_ID
LEFT JOIN PER_GRADES PG
ON PAAF.GRADE_ID=PG.GRADE_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS SCHOOL
ON PPG.SEGMENT5=SCHOOL.ORGANIZATION_ID
LEFT JOIN HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS ED
ON PPG.SEGMENT6=ED.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PAAF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > " +  (DT_STR, 25, 1252)@[$Package:YourDateParameter]
```